# select top 50 that travelled the most distance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am asked to fetch top 50 users who travelled the most distance. Show only the top 50 ignoring the ties at last position.

the output needs to be 2 columns. a persons name (user name) and distance travelled sorted in descending order and then by user name in ascending order

maybe partition needs to be used

2 tables : Users and Rides

```
Users:
id,
city_id,
name.
```

Rides:

```
id,
user_id,
distance.
```

My attempt:

```
select top 50 t1.name, sum(t2.distance) 
from users t1
inner join rides t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name
order by sum(t2.distance) desc
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle - please correct your tags.

Comment: @Dalek  here my attempt:

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: `TOP` is used in Sybase (SAP ASE) and SQL Server. Which database are you using?

Comment: mssql I can use mysql as well @TheImpaler

Comment: tagged sql server

Comment: Now you just need to add some sample data and desired results to have a complete question.

Comment: What is the issue with your current query?

Comment: what is the question? does your query generate a (syntax) error? does the query return nothing? does the query return the wrong result set (and if so then describe *what* is wrong about the result set)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTE with ranking and get result. When you apply DENSE_RANK, there will not be gaps in ranking.

```sql
DECLARE @t1 table(id int, name varchar(10))
declare @t2 table(id int,distance int)

insert into @t1 values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
insert into @t2 values(1,5),(1,5),(2,5),(2,5),(3,5);

;with cte_distance as
(
select t1.name, sum(distance) as totaldistance, dense_rank() over(order by sum(distance) desc) as rnk 
from 
@t1 as t1 
inner join @t2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id 
group by t1.name
)
select * from cte_distance where rnk < 50
```

| name | totaldistance | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 1 |
| b | 10 | 1 |
| c | 5 | 2 |